# Is it harmful for the engine to drive 60 mins of steep uphill every day?

Tags: car, driving

There is a road in my area which is steep uphill (about +15% slope). I have to pass it to reach my destination. It takes about an hour to drive across this road and I usually use 3rd or 4th gear to climb it.
I wanted to know, is it harmful for the engine if you drive uphill for 60 mins non-stop?

Answer (score 3):

No, my car spends its life driving up and down mountains.

As long as you service it and drive properly, like using the correct gear etc it will be fine.

Comment: What about driving uphill and immediately downhill after that? Does it harm the engine to cool down immediately?

Comment: Re read my answer... “up and down”...

Comment: I read your comment but you may drive up a hill and continue driving in a level ground and after that drive down another hill. My emphasis is on the duration between the too. That's why I said IMMEDIATELY. I'm worried about sudden changes of temperature inside the engine when the road pattern is something like A. Up and down without any stretch of road in between. Some say that this sudden temperature change may lead to the development of tiny cracks in cylinder head or the block.

Comment: My car has 229000k and I drive up the mountain, park for 5 mins to nip into the shop then drive back down. I wasa even teaching two sons to drive where we would go up, then directly down as it was a round trip. If the engine has faults it will fail anyway - unless you don't drive it at all, one customer I had said the worst thing for his fleet of trucks were the drivers...